Comparing list of lists
What I'm trying to do is given a list of lists like the one bellow:
inicialState(e([5, 5, 5], [6, 5, 5])).

I want to calculate the some of all the elements of one list and compare it to a certain value, for that I want to analyze the list of lists above and analyze each list separately and do the calculations, for example I want to see if 5+5+5, of the first list, is equal to "N" and print "True" or "False", then analyze the second list and see if 6+5+5 is equal to "N" and print the same thing.
The problem is the functions I have only print me a "no" in the console.
add([], 0).
add([H|T], Sum) :- add(T, Rest), Sum is H + Rest.

equal(_, []). 
equal(Target, [H|T]) :- add(H, Sum), write(Sum), (Target =:= Sum -> write('True') ; write('False')), equal(Target, T).

I call the following function:
testLists(Size) :-
    N is (Size + (Size*(Size*Size))) / 2,
    write(N),
    nl,
    inicialState(List),
    equal(N, List).

I tried doing the following function:
equal2(Target, Sum) :- nl, Target =:= Sum -> write('True') ; write('False').

The problem with this function is that it works, but only for one list, not a list of lists, and I have to call a separate function to add every element of the list like the one below:
add([], 0).
add([H|T], Sum) :- add(T, Rest), Sum is H + Rest.


A list of lists is... just a list of things to iterate over. What is the actual problem? Can use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2

e([5, 5, 5], [6, 5, 5]) is not a list of lists, it's a term e/2 of lists. If you had a list of lists then  ?- maplist(sum_list, [[5,5,5], [6,5,5]], Sums), memberchk(N, Sums). would do it.

In fact, e([5,5,5], [6,5,5]) is not a list of lists, but rather a term whose functor is e and whose arguments are lists. This is the main problem with your code. To solve it, you should write [[5,5,5], [6,5,5]] instead. I suggest the following modifications to your code:
initial_state([[5, 5, 5], [6, 5, 5], [4, 5, 6]]).

test_lists(Size) :-
    N is (Size + Size ^ 3) / 2, % use the exponentiation operator
    write(target = N),
    nl,
    initial_state(List),
    equal(List, N).

% By reversing the order of the arguments of equal/2, the spurious
% backtracking point is eliminated (avoiding the answer false).

equal([], _).
equal([L|Ls], Target) :-
    sum(L, Sum),
    write(Sum),
    (  Target =:= Sum
    -> write(' => True')
    ;  write(' => False') ),
    nl,
    equal(Ls, Target).

% Using an accumulator, the recursive process for computing the sum is
% transformed into an iterative one (tail-call optimization). 

sum(List, Sum) :-
    sum(List, 0, Sum).

sum([], Acc, Acc).
sum([First|Rest], Acc, Sum) :-
    Acc1 is Acc + First,
    sum(Rest, Acc1, Sum).

Example:
?- test_lists(3).
target=15
15 => True
16 => False
15 => True
true.

